# Is it possible in Kafka to create a log compacted topic where the oldest values are retained by compaction, for analytics purposes?

Tags: apache-kafka, analytics, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

Is it possible in Kafka to create a log compacted topic where the oldest values are retained by compaction (instead of the new ones), for analytics purposes? 
I have a query to create like

```
select k, min(d) from topic_src group by d
```

I am looking at ways using ksql / ksqldb / kstreams.
The simplest & most efficient way that comes to my mind is a log compacted topic or ktable to be created that retains oldest values for each key.

I am wondering if there is a possibility for a compaction to keep the oldest values, not the newest ones. If this is possible I would create a new topic with this custom policy to retain oldest values per key and have a ksql / kstreams pipeline to this new topic.

Alternatively I see a less clear/efficient possibility to create a table with window aggregation for the oldest values and then at query time, again, oldest values to be summarized. Here after the first value, all the subsequent batches on the same keys will add values that are not useful.

Comment: Can you give an example, maybe? `EARLIEST` seems like the kind of aggregation you're talking about, not `MIN`, but maybe I misunderstand

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible retain only the oldest values using log compaction.As this strategy cleans up the record and keeps the latest version of the key after given lag by log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms.

Here is some detailed explanation for log compaction.

https://www.quora.com/How-does-Kafka-s-log-compaction-work

https://medium.com/swlh/introduction-to-topic-log-compaction-in-apache-kafka-3e4d4afd2262

And, Topic configuration's by confluent.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html

I hope it answers the query.